# Do i need to use inheritance with my code in Java CRUD?

Tags: java, coding-style, crud

This is my code in establishing connection to MySQL Database

```
public class Database {

private final String server = "localhost";
private final String db = "hrmo_system";
private final String password = "12345";
private final String user = "root";

public Connection connection() {
    Connection database_connection;
    database_connection = null;
    try {

        database_connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + server + "/" + db + "", "'" + user + "'", password);

    } catch (SQLException err) {
        if (database_connection != null) {
            try {
                database_connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Database.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, err, "Database Exception", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    return database_connection;
}
```

}

I have 3 tables in my database.

> --- business
>
> --- taxpayers
>
> --- business_types

All of the codes in Creating, Deleting and Updating records in database are written in a class. Basically I name every class like

(table_name)Controller

> ex: TaxpayerController, BusinessController, BusinessTypeController

Sample Code in Controller class

```
public class TaxpayerBusinessController {

private final Database database = new Database();
private Connection connection = null;
private PreparedStatement ps = null;
private ResultSet rs = null;
private DefaultTableModel dtm;

public void view() {
    try {
        // Database Connection
        connection = database.connection();
        ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT id,last_name,first_name,middle_name FROM tax_payer");
        rs = ps.executeQuery();

        dtm.addRow(new String[]{
            rs.getString("id"),
            rs.getString("last_name"),
            rs.getString("first_name"),
            rs.getString("middle_name")
        });

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TaxpayerBusinessController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            connection.close();
            rs.close();
            ps.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TaxpayerBusinessController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}

public void store() {
    try {
        connection = database.connection();
        ps = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO (last_name,first_name,middle_name) VALUES (?,?,?) FROM tax_payer");

        ps.setString(0, TaxpayersEntry.txt_lastname.getText());
        ps.setString(1, TaxpayersEntry.txt_firstname.getText());
        ps.setString(2, TaxpayersEntry.txt_middlename.getText());

        ps.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TaxpayerBusinessController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            connection.close();
            rs.close();
            ps.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TaxpayerBusinessController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}


public void delete(){
    // Code in deleting.
}

public void update(){
    // Code in updating.
}
```

}

All table controllers are all written in format above

**Do I NEED to create a parent class? LIKE this:**

```
public class MainController {

Database database = new Database();
Connection connection = null;
PreparedStatement ps = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
DefaultTableModel dtm;

public void view() {
  
}
public void store(){
    
}
public void edit(){
    
}
public void update(){
    
}
public void delete(){
    
}
```

}

And extend the controller classes

```
public class TaxpayerBusinessController extends MainController {
    
   // Some code in here.

}
```

Please give me any comments and suggestions about my code.

and if possible,

Recommend some other coding style in CRUD.

*****EDIT

I am thinking about inheritance, since all of my controller classes have the same methods.

Comment: Unrelated, formatting: quote blocks aren't for arbitrary highlighting purposes; just makes it harder to read.

Comment: @DaveNewton i have just edited my formatting, is it readable now?